# Using SQL Group By while keeping same varchar values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that is returning two values.  I want to have the largest value so I do a group by, then MAX.  However, I have three other columns(varchar) that I would like to remain consistent with the id that is brought in with max.

Example.

```
OId     CId FName   LName   BName

18477   110 Hubba   Bubba   whoa
158     110 Test2   Person2 leee
```

What I want is
    OId     CId FName   LName   BName

```
18477   110 Hubba   Bubba   whoa
```

So I want to group them by CId. And O Id I want to keep the largest number.  I can't use Min or Max for the FName, LName, or BName because I want them to be the one with the OId that is selected. The FName, LName and BName for the other row I don't even want/need.

I tried using SELECT TOP, but that only pulls in literally one row and I need multiple.

**SQL**

```
INSERT INTO #CustomerInfoAll(FName, LName, BName, OwnerId, CustomerId)
SELECT
-- what goes here --(o.FirstName) AS FName,
-- what goes here --(o.LastName) AS LName,
-- what goes here --(o.BusinessName) AS BName,
MAX(o.OId) AS OId,
(r.CId) AS CId
FROM Owner o
INNER JOIN Report r
ON o.ReportId = r.ReportId
WHERE r.CId IN (SELECT CId FROM #ThisReportAll)
AND r.Completed IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY r.CId
ORDER BY OId DESC;
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: The SQL Server that I am currently using is 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have SQL Server 2005 or higher:

```
INSERT INTO #CustomerInfoAll (FName, LName, BName, OwnerId, CustomerId)
SELECT
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   BusinessName,
   Id,
   CId
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.CId ORDER BY o.Id DESC),
         o.Id,
         r.CId,
         o.FirstName,
         o.LastName,
         o.BusinessName
      FROM
         dbo.Owner o
         INNER JOIN dbo.Report r
            ON o.ReportId = r.ReportId
      WHERE
         EXISTS ( -- can be INNER JOIN instead if `CId` is unique in temp table
            SELECT *
            FROM #ThisReportAll tra
            WHERE r.CId = tra.CId
         )
         AND r.Completed IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY
         o.Id,
         r.CId,
         o.FirstName,
         o.LastName,
         o.BusinessName
   ) x
WHERE
   x.Seq = 1;
```

- DO use full schema names on all your objects (`dbo.Owner` and `dbo.Report`).
- DO use a semi-join (an `EXISTS` clause) or `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN` when possible.

Comment: Gee, thanks! I appreciate it. There are other ways to accomplish it but I gave you a decent one. For *extremely large* queries, there are other techniques that could perform better, but this is one of the most straightforward ways.